# Windows Phone 8 Pivot control virtualization

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, virtualization

I am trying to make an image scrolling app that scrolls images on swipe, the problem is 
all my images are loaded in memory at once when my app starts.
Can anyone tell how to implement virtualization?

C#:

```
 public ObservableCollection<im> imagelist { get; set; }

public ImageGalaryUc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        imagelist = new ObservableCollection<im>();
        this.DataContext = this;
       // ImageStack.ItemsSource = new VirtualSongList();
        this.Loaded += ImageGalaryUc_Loaded;
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Controls:Pivot x:Name="ImageStack" ItemsSource="{Binding imagelist}" >

                <Controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="{Binding bimage}" />

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            </Controls:Pivot>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this sample 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Basic-Lens-sample-359fda1b

It contains a component called media viewer - which implements pretty similar behaviour and virtualises.